# calling a function with a function as a parameter

Tags: javascript

The code below outputs:

```
x
x
x
x
x
1
Uncaught TypeError: func is not a function
```

I conclude that the reason why the second function call results in an error is due to function signature mismatch, but if it is so why does it print out the first `1`, and then the error message? Isn't it supposed to print out nothing at all after printing out `x` five times if there is an error?

```js
function runTheFunctionNTimes(func, n) {
    for (let i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    func()
  }
}

function functionWithoutParameters() {
    console.log('x')
}

function functionWithAParameter(y) {
    console.log(y)
}

runTheFunctionNTimes(functionWithoutParameters,5)
runTheFunctionNTimes(functionWithAParameter(1),5)
```

Comment: `functionWithAParameter` doesn't return a new function

Comment: The difference between `func` and `func()` is that `func` is a reference of a function, but `func()` is the computed value of a function.

Comment: Instead of calling the function upfront, passing its result, you can bind the parameter `1` and then pass the function : `runTheFunctionNTimes(functionWithAParameter.bind(null, 1), 5)`

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that `functionWithAParameter(1)` won't return a new function that can be called by `runTheFunctionNTimes`. You'll want to wrap it in an anonymous function (or arrow function) that wraps your function call. This way, `runTheFunctionNTimes` will call the arrow function which then calls your function with parameters. Like this:

```js
function runTheFunctionNTimes(func, n) {
  for (let i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    func()
  }
}

function functionWithoutParameters() {
  console.log('x')
}

function functionWithAParameter(y) {
  console.log(y)
}

runTheFunctionNTimes(functionWithoutParameters, 5)
runTheFunctionNTimes(() => functionWithAParameter(1), 5)
```

Your original code runs `functionWithAParameter` once because it evaluates from inside the function call, but then passed `undefined` (its return value) to `runTheFunctionNTimes`.

Comment: Why does it print out the first "1" if it not the way we are supposed to call it?

Comment: runTheFunctionNTimes(() => functionWithAParameter(1), 5) outputs 1, and then the error message. I was expecting it to output only the error message.

Comment: @iwsnmw I've edited my answer to explain that a bit. Basically, `functionWithAParameter` will be run once, but then it will pass `undefined` to `runTheFunctionNTimes`.

Comment: @iwsnmw If my answer best helped you, then consider marking it as correct. This will help guide others with the same issue in the future, by indicating my answer solved your issue.

Answer (score 0):

When you pass `functionWithoutParameters` into `runTheFunctionNTimes`, you are passing the actual function object in, which you can later invoke with your `func()` call.

However, when you pass `functionWithAParameter(1)` into runTheFunctionNTimes, you are first invoking `functionWithAParameter` with an argument of 1, and then passing the returned value of this function into `runTheFunctionNTimes`.  Since `functionWithAParameter` doesn't return anything, you are passing some kind of null-esque value into `runTheFunctionNTimes`.  So then later, `runTheFunctionNTimes` will essentially attempt to invoke `null()`, which is obviously garbage.

To accomplish something like what you are doing, you should look into the .bind method.  I think what you are looking for is probably
`runTheFunctionNTimes(functionWithAParameter.bind(this, 1), 5);`

Answer (score 0):

When a function name has parenthesis after it, it is called/executed. You can think of function execution as running the function and the replacing it with the return value. So the execution of that last line would look like this:

```js
runTheFunctionNTimes(functionWithAParameter(1),5)
```

`functionWithAParameter(1)` is run, `console.log` is run, and then returns `undefined`:

```js
runTheFunctionNTimes(undefined,5)
```

`runTheFunctionNTimes` is run with `undefined` as a parameter:

```js
for (let i = 0; i < n; i++) {
  // func is now equal to undefined and an error is thrown
  func()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a closure which returns a function for repeating.

```js
function runTheFunctionNTimes(func, n) {
    for (let i = 0; i < n; i++) func();
}

function functionWithoutParameters() {
    console.log('x');
}

function functionWithAParameter(y) {
    return function () {
        console.log(y);
    };
}

runTheFunctionNTimes(functionWithoutParameters, 5);
runTheFunctionNTimes(functionWithAParameter(1), 5);
```